# How to wait for Runnable finish?

Tags: android, andengine, runnable

I have a method named loadBalls(). In this method, I called another method named removeOldBalls(). 
In removeOldBalls(), I have a runnable to detach children on the scene. 
Below are 2 methods :

```
public static void loadBalls() {
    removeOldBalls();

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BALL; i++) {
        int x = MathUtils.random(0, CAMERA_WIDTH - BALL_SIZE);
        int y = BALL_SIZE;
        final Ball ball = new Ball(x, y, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE, GraphicsManager.trBalloons[i]);

        scene.registerTouchArea(ball);
        balls.add(ball);
        if (!balls.get(i).hasParent()) {
            scene.attachChild(balls.get(i));
        }
        Log.e("test", "load");
    }

}

public static void removeOldBalls() {
    ((BaseLiveWallpaperService) LWP.context).runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Log.e("test", "remove");
            scene.detachChildren();
        }
    });

    if (balls != null) {
        int length = balls.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            fsw.destroyBody(balls.get(i).body);
        }
        balls.clear();
        Log.e("test", "clear");
    }

}
```

What I need is all children are removed before adding new ones. But when running above source code, the children are added first, then removed.
Please tell me how to wait for removing finish before adding.

Comment: you need to keep the runnable instance as thread, and call the join() the method whenever you want to wait for its finish line check [this](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#trbeh)

Comment: or just call `loadBalls()` from - and at the end of `removeOldBalls()`

Comment: maybe you need to refresh(repaint) the container just after you remove the balls

Comment: Hi user2511414,

The problem that the source code in removeOldBalls() is called after loadBalls(). So all the balls are cleared

Answer (score 1):

I think look for the class [android.os.Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Then you can create two threads: one to remove all the children and another to add the children. Then add those threads to the Handler like this:

```
handler.post(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
              // Thread to remove children                    
            }
        });

handler.post(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
              // Thread to add children                 
            }
        });
```

Once you add them one after another the Android SDK will execute them in the order they were added. So that will take care of your ordering issue.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code which adds the children to another method, for example `addBalls`:

```
private void addBalls() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BALL; i++) {
        int x = MathUtils.random(0, CAMERA_WIDTH - BALL_SIZE);
        int y = BALL_SIZE;
        final Ball ball = new Ball(x, y, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE, GraphicsManager.trBalloons[i]);

        scene.registerTouchArea(ball);
        balls.add(ball);
        if (!balls.get(i).hasParent()) {
            scene.attachChild(balls.get(i));
        }
        Log.e("test", "load");
    }
}
```

And call this method fron the `run` method of the `Runnable` *after* you call `scene.detachChildren`:

```
public void run() {
    Log.e("test", "remove");
    scene.detachChildren();
    addBalls();
}
```